# Prove that for all integers $n$, $3$ does not divide $n^2-5$ using modular arithmetic.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I am having trouble proving that for all integers $n,\ 3$ does not divide $n^2-5$ using modular arithmetic. I know that $3\not\mid n^2-5$ means $n^2\not\equiv 5\pmod 3$. But I'm not sure how to start the proof.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note $5 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, so $n^2 \not\equiv 5 \pmod{3} \implies n^2 \not\equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, with this helping to show why the proposed duplicate applies to proving what you're requesting.

Answer (score 2):

The only squares mod $3$ are $0$ and $1$. Try this yourself: take the possible remainders mod $3$, square them, and then mod $3$ and see what you get. Now $-5 \equiv 1$ mod $3$. But then $n^2-5 \equiv n^2 + 1$ mod $3$, which can only take values $1$ or $2$ mod $3$. But because this remainder is never $0$, it cannot be divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1:
$$n\equiv 0\pmod 3\Rightarrow n^2\equiv 0\pmod 3\Rightarrow n^2-5\equiv -5\pmod 3\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$$

Case2:
$$n\equiv 1\pmod 3\Rightarrow n^2\equiv 1\pmod 3\Rightarrow n^2-5\equiv -4\pmod 3\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$$

Case 3:
$$n\equiv 2\pmod 3\Rightarrow n^2\equiv 1\pmod 3\Rightarrow n^2-5\equiv -4\pmod 3\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is an $a$ such that $3|(a^2-5)$.

Now, take $n=a-3$.

And see $(a^2-5)-(n^2-5)=3(2a-3)$. This means if $3|(n^2-5)$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$ then all $(n-3k)^2-5, k \in \mathbb Z$  is divisible by $3$.

If there is such $n$ anywhere far apart, that would be near us also. As we can't find any such $n$ in between $0$ and $3$, it's nowhere.